# how to share an secondary user store in multi tenant?

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I define 2 tenant in wso2 identity server 5.1, for example tenant TA, tenant TB.
Then login with TA and add an userStore in TA and login with TB and add same userstore in TB, that i want an userstore share in each two tenant. when IS is started and login with each tenant, when i want fetch user list, add user or any operation  on user i get this error:

```
    [2016-09-14 09:24:03,675] rasa-novin.admin@rayanen.com@rasa-novin.tenant [2] [IS]DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.UserStoreDeploymentManager} -  The deployment of enbcas_local.xml is not valid.
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Could not initialize new user store manager : enbcas.local Duplicate domain names not allowed.
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.callSecure(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:158)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.addSecondaryUserStoreManager(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:4078)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.UserStoreDeploymentManager.deploy(UserStoreDeploymentManager.java:68)
        at org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.store.configuration.deployer.UserStoreConfigurationDeployer.deploy(UserStoreConfigurationDeployer.java:167)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:807)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:144)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:377)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254)
        at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.loadServices(DeploymentEngine.java:135)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.TenantAxisConfigurator.deployServices(TenantAxisConfigurator.java:599)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.utils.TenantAxisUtils.createTenantConfigurationContext(TenantAxisUtils.java:369)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.utils.TenantAxisUtils.getTenantConfigurationContext(TenantAxisUtils.java:148)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil.onSuccessAdminLogin(CarbonAuthenticationUtil.java:134)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.services.authentication.AuthenticationAdmin.login(AuthenticationAdmin.java:117)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
        at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:117)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
        at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:169)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportReceiver.processMessage(LocalTransportReceiver.java:82)
        at org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.local.CarbonLocalTransportSender.finalizeSendWithToAddress(CarbonLocalTransportSender.java:45)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.local.LocalTransportSender.invoke(LocalTransportSender.java:77)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:430)
        at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:225)
        at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
        at org.wso2.carbon.authenticator.stub.AuthenticationAdminStub.login(AuthenticationAdminStub.java:659)
        at org.wso2.carbon.authenticator.proxy.AuthenticationAdminClient.login(AuthenticationAdminClient.java:64)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.DefaultCarbonAuthenticator.doAuthentication(DefaultCarbonAuthenticator.java:119)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.AbstractCarbonUIAuthenticator.handleSecurity(AbstractCarbonUIAuthenticator.java:218)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.BasicAuthUIAuthenticator.authenticate(BasicAuthUIAuthenticator.java:83)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.CarbonUILoginUtil.handleLogin(CarbonUILoginUtil.java:380)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.CarbonSecuredHttpContext.handleSecurity(CarbonSecuredHttpContext.java:244)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:60)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.wso2.carbon.ui.filters.CRLFPreventionFilter.doFilter(CRLFPreventionFilter.java:59)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:504)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1698)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.security.PrivilegedActionException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.callSecure(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:148)
        ... 77 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager$2.run(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:151)
        ... 79 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Could not initialize new user store manager : enbcas.local Duplicate domain names not allowed.
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.addSecondaryUserStoreManager(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:4095)
        ... 84 more
```

what is my problem?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the same scenario with IS 5.1.0 (standalone setup) and it works fine. I have used `org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager` as the secondary user store.

A secondary user store can be shared among tenants, but you need to configure them separately in all the tenants. And the user store domain name should be unique within the tenant. Once a new user store created, the respective XML configuration file is created at `<IS_HOME>/repository/tenants/<TENANT_ID>/userstores` directory.

Can you please [verify the setup again](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Configuring+Secondary+User+Stores)? If the problem it still there please share the list of files in `<IS_HOME>/repository/tenants/<TENANT_ID>/userstores/` directories?

Comment: I  have tried same as you, that had a unique domain name for store in each two tenant and had been made two XML configuration file  separately under own tenant folders,  but this error : Could not initialize new user store manager : enbcas.local (mine define domain) Duplicate domain names not allowed. I think it causes that  when call for example this method: remoteUserStoreMAnageClient.getUserClaimValue(username, claimURI, default); throw exception because cant find proper tenant from share domain name that exit in username value. notice that calling username param value had been tenantware.